# VBA Access and SQL Run-time Error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax-error

I'm trying create a button that sorts by most recent consent filed date if TwoMinInt_Complete checkbox is unchecked. So far it's giving me "Run-time Error '13': Type mismatch" and pointing to frm.SetRecordsource section. I believe it is the syntax that I'm not quite good at. Let me know if any questions.

```
Private Sub cmdNeeds2MinInterview_Click() 
Dim frm As IExtendedForm
If TypeOf Me.Parent Is IExtendedForm Then
   Set frm = Me.Parent
   frm.SetRecordsource _
      Filter = "Junction_ID IN SELECT Junction_ID FROM [nka_USBankVU_TwoMinInterview] WHERE [TwoMinInt_Complete] = True" & _
      OrderBy = "[Consent_Filed_Date] DESC"
   End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: With your suggestions I edited it to the following:

```
frm.SetRecordsource _
            Filter:=("Junction_ID IN SELECT Junction_ID FROM [nka_USBankVU_TwoMinInterview] WHERE [TwoMinInt_Complete] = True"), OrderBy:="Consent_Filed_Date DESC"
```

and getting different error:

[image: Error]

Comment: are the parameters supposed to be `=` only? or `:=`?

Comment: Along with `:=` you also need a comma between the two parameters.

Comment: frm.SetRecordsource _
            Filter:=("Junction_ID IN (SELECT Junction_ID FROM [nka_USBankVU_TwoMinInterview] WHERE [TwoMinInt_Complete] = True")), OrderBy:="Consent_Filed_Date DESC"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your True to -1

```
Private Sub cmdNeeds2MinInterview_Click() 

Dim frm As IExtendedForm
If TypeOf Me.Parent Is IExtendedForm Then
Set frm = Me.Parent
frm.SetRecordsource _
  Filter = "Junction_ID IN SELECT Junction_ID FROM [nka_USBankVU_TwoMinInterview] WHERE [TwoMinInt_Complete] = -1" & _
  OrderBy = "[Consent_Filed_Date] DESC"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So the Error was on Syntax, here's my final code:

```
Private Sub cmdNeeds2MinInterview_Click()
Dim frm As IExtendedForm
  If TypeOf Me.Parent Is IExtendedForm Then
    Set frm = Me.Parent
      frm.SetRecordsource _
  Filter:="Junction_ID IN (SELECT Junction_ID FROM [nka_USBankVU_TwoMinInterview] WHERE [TwoMinInt_Complete] = false)", OrderBy:="Consent_Filed_Date DESC"
   End If
End Sub
```

Thanks all for the input! :)

Comment: This is @mehow comment. Your'd better invite him to give you an answer here to conclude it...